# Salesforce Apex Best Practice

Tags: apex

this is my first ever question so I'm unsure how to word it whilst following any guidelines... but here it goes.

I'm creating a trigger so that when a new candidate is created (custom object) it will create a new contact to go with it given that there is not already a contact with the same email. The email field is unique & required on the candidate object, obviously meaning the same email can't be used twice but should I add some extra code inside my trigger just to confirm there are no contacts with the candidate's email that already exist? Or is simply having the unique box checked good enough?

Thanks ( if you're able to understand what I'm on about :) ),
Cameron.

Comment: welcome to SFSE; please see [ask] on getting the most from the Community.

Comment: Hi Cameron, and welcome to SFSE! There's no need for TIA (Thanks In Advance) or any variant, nor do you need to sign your name (it's already there for you at the bottom of the question). Otherwise, your question is perfectly fine, though you also could have included some pseudo-code to demonstrate your question We hope you'll enjoy your stay here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll still want to query the contacts to see if the email already exists. It's not extra code, it's code you'll want to have to make sure those contacts don't exist (they may have been independently created), and also so you can link the contact to the candidate record.